# typescript type narrowing `data` is not undefined when `error` is undefined

Tags: typescript, types, narrowing

I have the following interface for HTTP response

```
interface HTTPResponse<T> {
  ok: boolean, 
  error?: HTTPError; 
  data?: T, 
  init: ResponseInit
}
```

and this type narrowing check

```
export function isHTTPError(object: any): object is HTTPError {
  return "error" in object && object.ok === false;
}
```

when I pass a response through the `isHTTPError` check, typescript can tell if this is an error response and knows that `error` can't be undefined at this point.

If the response is not an error how to tell typescript that `data` is definitely present and should not be treated as possibly undefined?

---

At this moment I am using the following function

```
export function isHTTPSuccess<T>(object: any): object is T {
  return "data" in object && object.ok === true;
}
```

but this requires checking the response twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want [a discriminated union](https://css-tricks.com/typescript-discriminated-unions/), where `ok` is the discriminant.

You need two types. One for the success case, and another for the error case.

```
interface HTTPResponseSuccess<T> {
  ok: true
  error?: undefined
  data: T
  init: ResponseInit
}

interface HTTPResponseError {
  ok: false
  error: HTTPError
  data?: undefined
  init: ResponseInit
}
```

These have the same properties, but different types. This will, for example, allow typescript to know that if `ok` is `true` then there is no error and data exists.

Now you can build a union of these types to use when you don't know the result.

```
type HTTPResponse<T> = HTTPResponseSuccess<T> | HTTPResponseError
```

And now you can simply do:

```
// mock a response where you dont yet know if it was a success.
const res: HTTPResponse<number> = await someApi.getSomething()

if (res.ok) {
  console.log(res.data.toFixed())
}
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAEgKnACgUQE6oPaqgXigbwGdgBDYAV0IC4oA7cgWwCMJUAaKBiQwkgcwg1iqAJa0+AXwBQUscFYAzEgGNo8JACVuYDLUIQAyuWWqeAHjgA+AlKhQMAaxrBU5CLaitMqAPw1ytAAmEApiEIEegWQkNHAeYiLANFqEOnoQAJK0iVLSsrTyqEqqsAiIKWn6aN42do40SgA2+h5eWDTqKOhYkdF+UAHBobTh8dlJUBW6+lk5eaCQpZra0xAW1nidU+lGJtyE61AAPkvlK+nVPTIA9NecGMoOUCRQqOf6UADuABas0CAYchQQK6YBQEAQMEOWgYT5QEQKeFgz4kQjPKCEYymQgAOikwWUjRIbygymmYLe1FO230ZnozFY1hkCKgAApKTjHABKWqk6YYRoQHGNDB8dncHFRUg44AYABiIgAHuFWVyubkgA)